# get_postBackElement() is always undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" ScriptMode="Release" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        var elem = args.get_postBackElement();
        alert("begin " + elem.value);
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        alert("end request handler");
    }
</script>
```

This is my simple attempt to retrieve the postback element, triggered from my UpdatePanel. My update panel looks like this:

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_Project" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Project" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList_Customer" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I believe I have did everything correctly...

Any ideas?

Comment: To help verify, could you debug and see from the server what Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] is?

Comment: I am having this exact same problem.  Did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: @Jim - I didn't find an ASP.NET solution to this, as I hoped. I went with jQuery all the way (for that functionality).

Comment: @Jim The problem still exists in Microsoft's code. Please view my below answer.

Comment: @AshrafSabry Since [Microsoft isn't going to fix their bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/584991/clientidmode-static-in-updatepanel-fails-to-do-async-postback), my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28387666/612151) is the only way to use ClientIDMode="Static" without postback issues.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the ClientIDMode property value of the control (the DropDownList_Customer drop down list in this case) to AutoID. Please view my reply [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/ajax/radajax-broken-in-vs-2010-beta-2-in-master-content-pages.aspx#2921560).

Answer (score 1):

What is your postback trigger ? This control seems to be missing `DropDownList_Customer`

```
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList_Customer" />
```

Comment: It's declared outside of the `UpdatePanel` and looks like this `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Customer" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>`

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this pain, here's my solution.

Basically we just need to override Microsoft's **_uniqueIDToClientID** function so it doesn't ignore our Static client Ids on postback elements.

You'll just need to add the following code at the bottom of your page.

```
if (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager) {
  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

  prm._uniqueIDToClientID = function (uniqueID) {
    var clientID = uniqueID.replace(/\$/g, "_");
    if (document.getElementById(clientID)) {
      return clientID;
    }

    var lastDollar = uniqueID.lastIndexOf("$");
    if (lastDollar === -1) {
      return clientID;
    }

    if (lastDollar+1 > uniqueID.length) {
      return clientID;
    }

    var staticID = uniqueID.slice(lastDollar + 1);

    return document.getElementById(staticID) ? staticID : clientID;
  };
}
```

Now, **get_postBackElement()** in your BeginRequestHandler will no longer be undefined!

Just make sure our code is executed after Microsoft's MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js because we are overriding its **_uniqueIDToClientID** function.

> **Note**: My function always returns the default WebForms ClientID if the element exists on the page. Only if the element cannot be found on
>   the page, does it check to see if an element with a static ID exists
>   on the page. If it exists, the staticID is used, otherwise it
>   defaults back to the default WebForms ClientID.

Comment: Yes, my answer is old, and later I knew how to fix it by overriding _uniqueIDToClientID (it's mentioned somewhere here on SO). It's sad that MS won't fix it.